# Changing personalisation string with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can you change a personalization string with AMPscript?

Depending on the AMPscript formula I would like to change a personalization string, specifically the analytics.

Our goal is to send dynamic content track the different emails within Google Analytics.

The personalization string I'm focusing on is:

`%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%`

Is this possible? I'm not sure where to begin with AMPscript.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how exactly you want to use Personalization Strings in AMPscript. As far as I understand, you wanted to use it in AMPscript formulas (IF statement, for example). So that's possible.

Generally, Personalization Strings are a part of AMPscript. Take a look at:

[Personalization Strings and AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/personalizationStringsAMPscript.htm)

[Personalization Strings in Email Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)

*I'm not sure where to begin with ampscript.* Look at this docs
[Get Started with AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/getStarted-AMPscript.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Since that particular personalization string is set in the Email Properties, you can't change it's value or make it dynamic with AMPscript.

[image: Additional Email Attributes]

Do you have the [**Web Analytics Connector**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5) configured?  That'd be the place for updating what gets automatically appended to the URLs.  SFMC Support can help you with that.